# Numerical scheme for first order partial differential equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Does anyone know some numerical methods for solving such equations?
$$
\begin{cases} 
V_t + \langle V_x,\, F(t, x) \rangle = 0\\
V(0, x) = h(x)  
\end{cases},
\quad 0 \leqslant t \leqslant T,
$$
where
$$x \in \mathbb{R}^n,\quad V\,\colon\, \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\quad F\,\colon\, \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n,\quad h\,\colon\, \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$$
In my specific case $F$ has the form
$$F_1(t,\,x_1,\,x_2) = x_1,$$
$$F_2(t,\,x_1,\,x_2) = g_1(t)\, x_1^2 + g_2(t)\,x_1 + g_3(t).$$
All functions are continuous.

Comment: What do you mean by $\langle V_x, F \rangle$? If it's just a dot product, then I guess what you have in mind is $\nabla V \cdot F$, right?

Comment: You can use forward Euler with an upwind scheme for $\nabla V$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upwind_scheme.